# Non-BTree data structure where inserts are done in a sorted manner but i can later remove objects from random places

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, stl, big-o

I want to find an object with O(logN) and also remove with O(log N) - but no go to balanced tree implementation..

Any idea's for that?

Comment: you could use a skip list, but what's wrong with balanced trees? also, your question isn't clear on whether you want to be able to add elements after intialization - if not, you can use a plain array and just flag removed elements...

Answer (score 2):

[Fenwick tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree)

Answer (score 1):

[B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)

Comment: +1 for answering the question in the title, -1 for ignoring that the questioner (without giving any reason) specified no balanced tress.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a skip-list. It's probabilistic data-structure with logarithmic insertion/search/removal, but without the complex balancing code of trees.